# Is there a fitness app which can record my workouts across multiple activities?

Tags: fitness

I've been using MyTracks for tracking my running, and another app (which I forget the name) to record my cycling routes.

I also do gym, swimming and karate, is there an app which lets me keep track of my fitness workouts across multiple activities? I.e, I don't want to have an app for each one, its annoying.

I'd like to record things like time spent training, lengths/laps (for swimming), possibly bike/rowing/treadmill times/speeds/distances for the gym etc.

This will allow me to track myself over a period of time and see how much I've increased the duration/effort in my training.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Try out [Cardio Trainer](http://www.worksmartlabs.com/cardiotrainer/about.php).

[image: QR-Code]

It is able to record many types of workouts including walking, running, weight lifting, swimming (do you rely on your water-proof case?), yoga. You can also prepare your own custom routine (never tried that, but in your case, it might come handy).